# Serial Port And pygtk Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, python, pygtk

I need a example which is received data from serial port and show it to textview. I am using python and pygtk( and glade to design my form) I was try many time but I am not successful!
Thanks for any help !!!

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what's the question, but the answer could well be [PySerial](http://pyserial.readthedocs.io/en/latest/). It also comes with a ports console tool to visualize the content communicated to serial ports.